# How do I return a value of an entity in a table that is less than but closest to the value in another table for each element in the last table in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables in MS Access and I am trying to add a field for one of those tables that tells which record from another table has a value that is less than the first field's value, but comes the closest?  I have this query so far (just a select statement to test output and not alter existing tables), but it lists all values that are less than the querying value:

```
SELECT JavaClassFileList.ClassFile, ModuleList.Module
FROM JavaClassFileList, ModuleList
WHERE ModuleList.Order<JavaClassFileList.Order;`
```

I tried using things like`SELECT JavaClassFileList.Classfile, MAX(ModuleList.Module)`, which will only display the maximum module but combined it with the select statement above, but it would say that it would only return one record.

Output desired:  I have some records, a, b, and c, I shall call them, each storing various information, while a is storing a value of 732 in a column, and b is storing a value of 731 in the same column.   c is storing a value of 720.  In another table, d is storing a value of 730 and e is storing a value of 718.  I want the output like this (they are ordered largest to smallest):

- a 732 d 730
- b 731 d 730
- c 720 e 718

There can be duplicates on the right, but no duplicates on the left.  How can I get this result?

Comment: Unfortunately, most of your question is noise. Important things to add when asking for SQL-queries are: table structure (including primary and foreign key constraints)and exactly what you want to accomplish (preferably with sample data and desired results).

Comment: primary keys are ClassFile for JavaClassFileList, Module for ModuleList, and Method for FunctionMethodList.  I have not specified any foreignkeyconstraints because I did not see the need to as this is simply to organize already existing data and present it in a more useful form.  The foreign key in JavaClassFileList is ModuleMembership (uses Module in ModuleList, but as specified in above problem). Originally, the database was just one table consisting of a list of everything (regardless of whether it was a method, class, or module).  They were numbered based on their order in that raw table.

Comment: Sample results:  in JavaClassFileList, first two classfiles have Order equal to 725 and 720 respectably.  These two classes both belong to the same module.  That module has Order equal to 719, with the one after equal to 713.  I want to return for those two classes the closest module by order that is less than the order value of the classes.

Comment: When you used `SELECT JavaClassFileList.Classfile, MAX(ModuleList.Module)` did you also use `GROUP BY JavaClassFileList.Classfile`? If so then you should not have just had one row, but one row per classFile wich appears to be the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this type of query using a correlated subquery.  I think the following words in Access:

```
SELECT jc.ClassFile,
       (select top 1 ml.Module
        from ModuleList as ml
        where ml.[Order] < jc.[Order]
       )
FROM JavaClassFileList as jc;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming Order is unique for Module. If it isn't, JavaClassFileRecords may show up multiple times in the resultset.

If no module can be found for a JavaClassFile then it will not show up in the results. If you do want it to show up in cases like that (with a null module), replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT j.ClassFile, m.Module
FROM JavaClassFileList j
INNER JOIN ModuleList m
ON m.Order =
    (SELECT MAX(Order)
     FROM ModuleList
     WHERE Order < j.Order)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, either because the syntax was not recognized or produced weird results when combined with another query.  See the question I asked later after this one (which is basically a rewording and different presentation of this question), for the answer I found helped the most.

Comment: It was a good idea though.  I tried it in a different database and it worked perfectly.  Don't know why it wasn't working for me on the other one, think it was partly due to the copy-paste-nature of the table, since it was coming from excel.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066604/how-do-i-create-a-query-that-returns-multiple-results-from-comparisons-but-with